# How to setup Eclipse CDT 8 with OpenCV 2.3 in Windows?

Tags: opencv, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to setup Eclipse CDT 8 with OpenCV 2.3 in Windows 7 32.

Firstly, I tried downloading OpenCV 2.3 and setting up with eclipse according to [this tutorial](http://carrierfrequency.blogspot.com/2011/05/opencv-22-in-windows-using-eclipse-ide.html) (some minor different steps..):

After that, I got some "undefined reference to" errors.
Then, I found out I had to recompile using Mingw32, so I did as [this tutorial](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/MinGW) explains (I didn't use the part where it runs the demo file).

So, I ended up with my lib files in C:\opencvbin\lib (I chose this directory in CMake).

Inside Eclipse, I included the original source from OpenCV (in my case C:\OpenCV2.3\build\include).

To test the setup, I got the convexhull.cpp from C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\samples\cpp, compiled with no errors, 
but when I run the exe, there is no result.
Also, the debug seems not adjusted. This is the debug output in Eclipse:

```
[New Thread 6480.0x1994]
```

Is there anything missing during this setup?

If there is no apparent issue, please let me know so I can put more details.

ps: I chose this title because the question contents may help someone else setting up the environment. I can change if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the DLL's from C:\opencvbin\bin in the same path where your .exe is (the compiled demo).

Answer (score 0):

A probably better alternative to copying the DLL's to you current directory is adding the directory containing them to PATH (and rebooting).